# How can I have Google Checkout charge a subscription every 2, 3 or more years (longer-than-yearly)? Can PayPal do this?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, google-checkout

Is it possible (and, if so, how) can I have Google Checkout charge someone for a magazine subscription every 2 years (or 3 years or 5 years). The idea is someone pays for a 3 year subscription in 2010 and then is billed again for the next 3 years in 2013.

How can this be done?

If Google cannot do it, can PayPal?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably want to ask the folks at [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/).

Answer (score 0):

For Google Checkout the max period for recuring subscriptions is one year.

See the doc below for more info:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions.html